# An error occurred in the immediate operation of the program

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, android-permissions

I am creating a flutter app (music player) when I run the app using my device as emulator An error occurred in the immediate operation of the program , the program closes and the permission message appears, I click allow and go to open the app it is working fine, but why the app closed like something goes wrong.

this is my code of permission

`@override

```
void onInit() {
  // TODO: implement onInit
  super.onInit();
  checkPermission();
}
```

checkPermission() async{

```
  var perm = await Permission.storage.request();
  if(perm.isGranted){
   
  }else{
    checkPermission();
  }
}
```

`

this message in my vcode treminal

`Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...          34.7s W/xample.musicap(25714): Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;->getDisplay()Landroid/view/Display; (light greylist, linking) W/OnAudioQueryPlugin(25714): The application doesn't have access to the library E/AndroidRuntime(25714): FATAL EXCEPTION: main E/AndroidRuntime(25714): Process: com.example.musicapp, PID: 25714 E/AndroidRuntime(25714): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media from pid=25714, uid=10324 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission() E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1966) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1934) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:809) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:759) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:717) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at com.lucasjosino.on_audio_query.queries.AudioQuery$loadSongs$2.invokeSuspend(AudioQuery.kt:75) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664) E/AndroidRuntime(25714):        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@3043ab4, Dispatchers.Main.immediate] I/Process (25714): Sending signal. PID: 25714 SIG: 9 Lost connection to device. Syncing files to device SM N9500...`

these lines are exited

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

I checked the all package everything exited    `permission_handler: ^11.0.1`,

how I can solve this problem?

Comment: use proper use of permission handler in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

The checkPermission() recursively calls itself until the permission is granted, but this approach can issues
Try this code.

```
  Future<void> requestStoragePermission() async {
    PermissionStatus status = await Permission.storage.request();
    if (status.isGranted) {
      // Permission granted, you can proceed with your code
    } else {
      // Permission not granted, wait for a while and try again
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
      requestStoragePermission(); // Recursive call
    }
  }
```

Comment: I added this code in my project but the problem still excite, when I run the app is going to install in my phone but the app immediate closed and the message appears ( allow app ) I clicked allow , and i should looking for the app to open it , it is working fine but why the app closed

Comment: You do multiple task on app start time. 
To run a task separately from the main UI thread in Flutter, you can use Dart's Isolate class. Isolates are a way to achieve parallelism in Dart, allowing you to perform tasks concurrently without blocking the UI thread